# Redux-Form: setting "component" prop as "React.DOM.input" yields error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm creating a very simply input form in my react-redux app with redux-form. I'm following along the with the example of the redux-form page, but it's throwing me an error. The source of the error comes from trying to set the `component` prop to `React.DOM.input`. It throws this error:

```
TypeError: _react2.default.DOM is undefined
```

However, if I pass the string `'input'` into the `component` prop, it works fine, and I can see the changed state in my redux dev tool. I'm just reaaaaally not sure where I got the idea to put it as a string and now I'm super curious .

```
let SubsForm = ({ handleSubmit, availScripts }) => {
    const subs = availScripts.map(script =>
        [
            <label htmlFor={script}>{script}</label>,
            <Field key={script} component={React.DOM.input} type="checkbox" name={script} />,
            <br />,            
        ]
    );

    return [
        <form>
            {subs}
        </form>
    ];
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between `import ReactDOM from "react-dom"`, and `React.DOM`.

The `"react-dom"` package is what you need to render React components into an HTML page.

Meanwhile, `React.DOM` was a set of factory functions for creating virtual DOM elements in render methods.  It's been [moved out into a separate `react-dom-factories` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom-factories), and is no longer part of the main React package as of React 16.

`React.createElement()` takes either a React component type or a string DOM HTML element name as its first argument, .  The `React.DOM` factory functions wrapped up that process a bit.  So, these are identical:

```
React.createElement("input", {name : "myInput"});
React.DOM.input({name : "myInput"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the react component.

```
 import React from "react";
```